# Tabview in Landscape Orientation full screen

Tags: ios, swiftui, tabview

I am working on a `TabView` but I want to show an image that occupies the entire screen and the rest of the content in a normal way.

In vertical mode it works correctly but in horizontal mode part of the content bites the notch.

How can I correct this?

My code is as follows:

`ContentView.swift`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
                Home()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("first")
                        Text("First")
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)
            Text("Second View")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("second")
                        Text("Second")
                    }
                }
                .tag(1)
        } .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

`Home.swift`

```
struct Home: View {
    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Color(.red)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                ScrollView {

                    VStack {
                        Image("slider_concierto1")
                            .resizable()
                            //.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                            .frame(height: 250)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

                        VStack {

                            Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.")
                        }

                        .padding()
                            //.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)
                            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16) .foregroundColor(Color.green))
                            .padding()

                    }

                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width)

                } //scrollview

            } //GEO


        }//geo
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

[image: View image]

Comment: You're ignoring the safe areas `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` so the views will extend past the notch. Remove `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea` and the content won't expand past the notch.

Comment: But I need the image to occupy beyond the notch. The rest of the content does not.

Comment: Have you tried `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)`?